# C# Rhino mocks stubmethod with hard coded parameter in second call

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

This may not be something that's even possible but I thought I'd ask anyway. Is there anyway for me to stub out this method so that the second call is also stubbed out using the parameter provided in the method I'm testing?

The method to stub:

```
public SupportDetails GetSupportDetails(string languageKey)
{
    var result = FindSupportDetails(languageKey);

    return result ?? FindSupportDetails("en-us");
}
```

My Current test:

```
public void GetsUSDetails_IfLangKeyDoesNotExist()
{
    var langKey = "it-it";

    _repo.Stub(s => s.FindSupportDetails(langKey))
         .Return(supportDetails.Where(sd => sd.LanguageKey == langKey)
                               .SingleOrDefault());

    ISupportRepository repo = _repo;
    var actual = repo.GetSupportDetails(langKey);

    Assert.AreEqual("en-us", actual.LanguageKey);
}
```

and the supportDetails object used in the test:

```
supportDetails = new SupportDetails[]
        {
            new SupportDetails()
            {
                ContactSupportDetailsID = 1,
                LanguageKey = "en-us"
            },
            new SupportDetails()
            {
                ContactSupportDetailsID = 2,
                LanguageKey = "en-gb"
            },
            new SupportDetails()
            {
                ContactSupportDetailsID = 3,
                LanguageKey = "es-es"
            }
        };
```

Comment: I think you can just add another call, ie `_repo.Stub(s => s.FindSupportDetails("en-us")).Return(supportDetails.Where(sd => sd.LanguageKey == "en-us").SingleOrDefault());`

Comment: Won't that just overwrite the first stub?

Comment: I don't believe so, as the passed parameter is different. Been a while since I used Rhino, though. Otherwise use [the repeat syntax](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/mocking-comparison-part-6-multiple.html)

Comment: It appears to work so thanks for that. I don't really understand how it knows which stub to use for the call since the signatures are the same

Comment: @stuartd is right, rhinomocks doesn't override regular setups, however the correct way to handle your situation is to use `Do` method.

Answer (score 4):

The correct and the most elegant solution to your problem is to use `Do` method:

```
_repo.Stub(s => s.FindSupportDetails(null))
     .IgnoreArguments()
     .Do((Func<string, SupportDetails>) 
         (langKey => supportDetails.SingleOrDefault(sd => sd.LanguageKey == langKey)));
```

The `Func` will raise no matter what argument was passed to `FindSupportDetails`, then the correct `SupportDetails` will select.